# How do I remove painted knockdown texture?

Tags: drywall, removal, sanding, texture, popcorn

We scraped our popcorn ceilings and had somebody do knockdown texture in the whole house. Problem is, that when the guy went to prime over the texture, some of the texture started peeling off on the roller in the master bedroom and living room. There may have then several issues that caused this... Including mixing The Home Depot Tuf-Tex bag incorrectly, possibly the ceiling still had some popcorn dust on it, we're because we're in Florida, the humidity may have gotten to it.

I really believe the problem lies in the mixture or application... Because the guy inspected the ceiling, said we did a really good job, and even though we're in Florida by the water, the temperature has been low and relatively dry during this whole process. he tried to blame it on everything else but himself, but it didn't add up.

Anyhow, he went back and patched the parts that peeled off, but when we went to go paint over it with a sprayer using a pretty light coat, with in just a couple of hours it started spider cracking everywhere. All this is besides the point though...

I really fear just patching again because it could crack in other areas after we did the next layer of paint... And besides, especially in the living room, the cracking is bad all over the place... So we're considering taking it all down, and redoing everything from scratch, possibly using somebody else, and possibly priming prior to texturing.

At any rate... The texture comes off fairly easily on about 30% of this 14x22 ft ceiling. The issue is the other 70%, where removal seems fairly difficult even with water.

What I'm considering doing he is using a sander with a back attachment or something to try to at least get through some of the paint and primer before trying to wet scrape again. I've read about skim coating... But the ceiling, being 14 X 22, seems like a huge job to tackle that way properly.

Can anyone please recommend a decent sander to use? Hopefully one thats affordable since we've already spent so much money on this remodel.

Either that, or please offer an alternate method or tips to tackle this issue.

Please note that hanging new drywall underneath the old drywall is probably not an option because some of the walls have mirrors going all the way up to the ceiling and other trim that gets in the way. We could possibly replace the ceiling all together, if that seems like a huge daunting task... Let alone expensive.

Thanks in advance for any advice given!

Comment: Think about a small tapered edge molding for the ceiling with the thin edge toward the walls, and then 1/4" drywall overall.

Comment: There are no bare walls. :( Theres a rough plaster wall, a mirrored wall, a stone wall, and the 4th side is open with a wooden beam across the ceiling.

Comment: The molding is meant to make a frame on the ceiling to surround a new thin drywall application. It doesn't even have to go exactly to the edge, just serve as a transition from the thicker middle to the old level.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know that replacing the drywall for that little a space wouldn't be the best route.  Seems the cleanest.  Removing trim isn't hard.  I don't know about the mirrors, though. Renting a drywall jack is cheap and makes it a ton easier to hang.  A bit of demo and hanging a new ceiling sounds easier than messing around with something that isn't working out.

Beyond that, I don't know about knockdown texture, but sanding down a ceiling without a drywall sander sounds like it sucks and trying to water/scrape it sounds like it sucks and is super messy.  Demoing drywall is quick.

No expert here.  I'd just replace it.  Seems the surest, which is the direction I like to steer.

Answer (score 0):

You can buy or rent a drywall sander that has abrasive pads and a vacuum attachment that collects the dust. This is what I had to do when I experienced the same issue with my bathroom ceiling.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue as I described [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/99056/wall-texture-peeling-off)

I completely got rid of the texture by scraping it off. I used a Black and Decker matrix sander attachment (that's what I had) with 80 grit sandpaper.

To answer your question about the sander, this is what I used:
[image]

[Black & Decker](http://www.blackanddecker.com/products/power-tools/portable-power-tools/matrix-attachments/matrix-detail-sander-attachment/bdcmts)